# Position image beside vertical navigation bar

Tags: css, html

This here is my code, what I want to do is that I have to place images right next to the vertical navigation bar without disturbing the order of the list. I tried it many times but I wasn't successful, here is my code
THE HTML PART

```
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="#">»  Computers</a>
</li>

<li><a href="#">»  Storage Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >»  Networking Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#/">»  Security Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Office Automations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Projectors and Display     Screens</a></li>
<li><a href="#">»  Softwares</a></li> 
<li class="lastitem"><a href="#">»  Customized Solutions</a></li>       
</ul>
```

THE CSS PART(describes the behavior of the list only)

```
.navbar{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 10 0px;
width: 280px; /* width of menu */
position:absolute;
}

.navbar li{
border-bottom: 1px solid white; /* white border beneath each menu item */
}

.navbar li a{
background: #333 url(media/sexypanelright.gif) no-repeat right top; /*color of menu    by  default*/
font: bold 13px "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;
display: block;
color: white;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 0; /* Vertical (top/bottom) padding for each menu link */
text-indent: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

.navbar li a:visited, .navbar li a:active{
color: white;
}

.navbar li a:hover{
background-color: black; /*color of menu onMouseover*/
color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}
.navbar ul li:hover{
background-color: black;
color: #ff0066;
display:block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
opacity:0.75;
}
.navbar ul li:hover{    
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#666666;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#333333;
}
```

Comment: `sexypanelright.gif` : I guess this is not a Wikipedia restyling :D

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd2jQ/) to demo your solution. You may want to update it with `sexypanelright.gif`

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 40%;
}

.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: He would be forced to use an absolutely positioned image, certainly not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `position: absolute` and add `display: block; float:left` to `.navbar`.

And add an image with `float: left;`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5vcG/1/)

Comment: Your first suggestion was better, all you needed to do was put the image element above the list in the HTML, et voila!

Comment: But as I understood Chaitanya wanted to `place images right next to the vertical navigation bar`.

Comment: Initially I thought the OP might want **one image** to the left of the navigation, but I'm beginning to suspect they want icons next to each list item.

Comment: Yes, I want to place the image right next to the vertical navigation bar, i.e on the right hand side of the user. If I am inserting the img tag before or after the list then the image is hidden by the list itself.